# I can not launch my js Discord bot, error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I tried to follow a tutorial to make my own music discord bot but when I try to launch it I got some problems
I correctly installed the modules, and I've also made a json file that contain my token to make the bot,

[There is the command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZFGC.png)

and there is my code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const DisTube = require('distube');
const distube = new DisTube(client, { searchSongs: false, emitNewSongs: true });
const { token } = require('./info.json');
const prefix = '!';

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log('${client.user.tag} va venir faire mousser tout ça!');
});

client.on("message", async(message) => {
            if (message.author.bot) return;
            if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
            const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
            const command = args.shift();

            const status = (queue) => `Volume: \`${queue.volume}%\` | Filter: \`${queue.filter || "Off"}\` | Loop: \`${queue.repeatMode ? queue.repeatMode == 2 ? "All Queue" : "This Song" : "Off"}\` | Autoplay: \`${queue.autoplay ? "On" : "Off"}\``;

            distube
                .on("playSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(
                    `Joue :musical_note: et nique Brian \`${song.name}\` - \`${song.formattedDuration}\`\nDemandé par: ${song.user}\n${status(queue)}`
                ))
                .on("addSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(
                    `Ajoutée! ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\` to the queue by ${song.user}`
                ))
                .on("playList", (message, queue, playlist, song) => message.channel.send(
                    `Joue :musical_note: \`${playlist.name}\` playlist (${playlist.songs.length} songs).\nDemandé par: ${song.user}\nJoue mtn \`${song.name}\` - \`${song.formattedDuration}\`\n${status(queue)}`
                ))
                .on("addList", (message, queue, playlist) => message.channel.send(
                    `Ajouté \`${playlist.name}\` playlist (${playlist.songs.length} songs) to queue\n${status(queue)}`
                ))
                .on("searchResult", (message, result) => {
                        let i = 0;
                        message.channel.send(`**Choisi en dessous**\n${result.map(song => `**${++i}**. ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\``).join("\n")}\n*Tu as 60s pour choisir*`);
    })
    .on("searchCancel", (message) => message.channel.send(`Annulé batard`))
    .on("error", (message, e) => {
        console.error(e)
        message.channel.send("Call Souf ça bug: " + e);
    });
    if (command =="play") {
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('Tu ne peux pas entendre la douce mélodie.');
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Décide toi frère!');
        distube.play(message, args.join(" "));
    }
    if (command =="stop") {
        const bot = message.guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id);
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('Tu ne peux pas entendre la douce mélodie.');
        if (bot.voice.channel !== message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('Tu est pas dans le même channel que moi');
        distube.stop(message);
        message.channel.send('Tu as arreté la musique');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run v12.5.3 code when you have discord.js v13, that's why you get this error, it's missing intents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `discord.js v13` all bots are required to define their **intents** in the Client `constructor`.

Example:

change your

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

to

```
const {Client, Intents} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]});
```

You would obviously change the **intents** to what your bot would use.

More info can be found [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#intents)